# Long while loop might crash ros::Rate.sleep()?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`ros::Rate loop_rate(8);     // 8Hz while(ros::ok()) { Kalman_Filter.filter_control();       ros::spin_once(); loop_rate.sleep();              }`

The function Kalman_Filter.filter_control() is a state machine and one state runs on 1Hz, while the rest of the code runs on 8Hz. Will this crash loop_rate.sleep()?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321535/long-while-loop-might-crash-ros::rate.sleep()?/) by [RicoJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/40968/ricoj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2019-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No (or at least: not because the code takes too long, there could still be other problems with it of course).

It will just mean that `loop_rate.sleep()` will return immediately after the "one state [that] runs on 1Hz" has finished, as there is no more time to sleep.

> The function Kalman_Filter.filter_control() is a state machine and one state runs on 1Hz, while the rest of the code runs on 8Hz. Will this crash loop_rate.sleep()?

What makes you wonder whether it will crash? Also: what is a crash for you?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0